# How can I show selected option from list in textbox using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have the following form:

[image]

and in my easy mvc model (below is my View, this code populates values):

```
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ID)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.CustomerName)
            </td>
                <select id="decisionList" name="@item.ID">
                    <option selected value="b"></option>
                    <option value="n">None</option>
                    <option value="c">Cancellation</option>
                    <option value="d">Date of payment</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td>
                <input id="choice" name="@item.ID" type="text">
            </td>
            <td>
        </tr>
    }
```

What I want to do is to show text from selected list in **corresponding** textbox (so I choose some option in 3rd row for column 'Choice' and see this text in 3rd textbox of column 'Decision'). I tried different ways of doing it, I added attr 'name' with @item.ID to define each row field by ID from model (note: 'name' have spaces after the number')

I wrote some js. - goal is to input selected text upon changing selection.:

```
$('select#decisionList').change(function () {

    var textSelected = $(this).find(':selected').text();
    var nameSelected = $(this).attr('name');

    $('#choice').attr("[name*='"+ nameSelected +"']").val(textSelected);
   
});
```

It doesn't work at all. I have no idea how to do this. 'Foreach' assigns ID to each 'name' properly, as shown in the pic above.  Do you have idea how to show selected text in corresponding (in this case next-to field) field? Maybe my method shown here is useless

Comment: Why would you want to have two fields with the same `name=""` how would you differentiate them on server side?

Comment: Also, makes no sense to have the *"Decision"* field at all. A `<select>` is **already** a decision.

Comment: because I don't know how to show selected option in textbox and thought that maybe I'll try with the same 'name' for both: selecetd list and textbox. If you have other idea how should I solve pls give me a hint

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan I know what you mean but from some purpose I need this column

Comment: What is the ```console.log(textSelected)```?

Comment: Check https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/

Comment: Ok I know how to show selected option in textbox but i don't know how to show this value for **coresponding** field - in this case choice form second row should be shown in second row oc column 'Decision'

Comment: Also, your HTML markup is invalid, you have unclosed `<td>`

Comment: Also, duplicate IDs are invalid in HTML. That's pretty basic. Use classes instead.

Comment: @Tung there is some error: ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'val' of undefined
    at HTMLSelectElement.<anonymous> (Site.js:9)
    at HTMLSelectElement.dispatch (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3)
    at HTMLSelectElement.r.handle (jquery-1.12.4.min.js:3)```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Get the selected option *index* [HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/selectedIndex)
- Target the OPTION element using [SelectElement.options[*index*]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLSelectElement/options)
- Refer to the common TR parent by using jQuery's [.closest()](https://api.jquery.com/closest/)  method
- Find an element using jQuery's [.find()](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method

```js
$('.decisionList').on("change", function() {
  const i = this.selectedIndex;
  $(this).closest("tr").find(".choice").val(this.options[i].textContent);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>111</td>
    <td>Anna</td>
    <td>
      <select class="decisionList">
        <option selected value="b"></option>
        <option value="n">None</option>
        <option value="c">Cancellation</option>
        <option value="d">Date of payment</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input class="choice" name="111" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>222</td>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>
      <select class="decisionList">
        <option selected value="b"></option>
        <option value="n">None</option>
        <option value="c">Cancellation</option>
        <option value="d">Date of payment</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    <td><input class="choice" name="222" type="text"></td>
  </tr>
</table>



<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Or also this way in a more jQuery *fashion*:

```js
$('.decisionList').on("change", function() {
  const $option = $(this).find(":selected");
  $(this).closest("tr").find(".choice").val($option.text());
});
```